# Active Directory via ldap: smart way to combine calls to the same contact

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am using the php ldap library to work with active directory contact objects.

Currently, I have the following problem:

```
$dn = "****";
//adds an contact to active directory
ldap_add($dn);

sleep(25);

//returns the contact from active directory
ldap_query_for_contact($dn);
```

It takes around 25 seconds until I can find/get or modify an active directory contact after I added the contact to AD. I need to get the guid after adding the contact, so I have to wait for AD to give me those information but on the other hand, the user is also waiting for a reponse from the server and wants to do further operations connected to this contact.

Is this a known issue? I know that AD is not made for database purposes and is pretty slow in some use cases. But is there a clever way how I can work around this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why are you waiting for an answer from the AD ? If you created the contact, you already have his details

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The GUID is created by the active directory. So I do not have it. It is like, when you insert a new row into a database and then the database returns the Id. The thing is, active directory does not return the guid. You have to query for the guid...

Comment: Then can you retrieve it later or asynchronously ? You only need the DN to retrieve it

Comment: That is the question. What is the best way? Asynch in php means threading, right?

Comment: I was hoping, anyone had this issue before. I mean there must be more people working with ad via ldap and having to perform many calls over one contact that was added recently.

Comment: I am working with AD via LDAP on a PHP project but I have never been needing the GUID. I would use a workaround to avoid using Threads as I don't know much about them in PHP. you could retrieve the GUID in the next page your user sees, or in an AJAX call so that he is not blocked. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your support. Unfortunatly, sometimes the user is faster than 25 secs and this is where the struggle really starts.

Comment: Do you have more than one domain controller in your environment?

Comment: You need to bind to the same dc. In this case you can query the contact immediately after creation. Sleep is used to wait until replication finishes in multi dc environment. I'd recommend to avoid using sleep, as there may be situations when even 25 seconds is not enough. Always bind to the same dc and leave ad connection open, while performing ad requests to increase performance

Comment: Thanks alot for your support. I will try to continue one connection and have a check for the DC. Will let you now my results :)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. @oldovets You are right, we have two domain controllers running and right now for every ldap call the programm is opening a new connection to AD without specifying a domain controller. How can I bind to the same dc? Using the dc as the ip, for ldap connect, or do I specify the dc in the dn for every call to an specific contact? Like that: "LDAP://domaincontroller1/OU=test,dc=company,dc=co,dc=uk"

Comment: Have no experience with ldap in php but it should be similar to win api. ldap_connect returns you a handle. This handle should be then passed in all ldap_xxx functions and closed after all job is done

Comment: @oldovets Thanks a lot for your help, it worked out. I am now binding to one specific DC. The server ip can either be the active directory itself, or one specific DC. Using only one DC solved my delay problem. I would love to mark your comment as my answer, so just answer my question and I will mark it as solved. Also Gabriel Luci, thanks for your support!